# What does constructing an array by an object mean?

Tags: php, constructor

I am learning the source codes of a micro MVC framework (Slim), and confusing about the codes below: (https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Slim.php line 158)

```
$this->middleware = array($this);
```

I've never seen the syntax before, and wondering what does `array($this)` mean.

And at line 1094:

```
$this->middleware[0]->call();
```

But I noticed that this `Class Slim{}` doesn't implement an `ArrayAccess` interface, so how can it be accessed by index?

I've searched in the PHP manual page (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) but found nothing. So  I turning to here for help, thanks!

Comment: `$this->middleware` is an array, not an object. Item 0 of the array is the `Slim` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply creates an array with one object element.